# why does "Infinity==Infinity" in JavaScript becomes true?

Tags: javascript

As far as I know, in math both `Infinity` and `NaN` are vague values.
as all of us know:

```
console.log(NaN == NaN); //-> false
```

while

```
console.log(Infinity==Infinity); //-> true
```

I'm wondering why the result of the second code is `true`. I'm expecting that the result of the second one, should be `false`, but it's not.

Could you please help me out.
I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `Infinity`, not `infinity`?

Comment: @Timo 
yes, I mean "Infinity".

Comment: Fundamentally, NaN represents any possible non-numeric result of a numeric operation. It makes more sense that NaN is not equal to NaN, because not every non-numeric result is logically equivalent. Infinity is a bit more well defined, although one could argue about cardinalities of infinity, the notion of the extreme limit of the number line makes more sense mathematically to be equal to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers: **Because the spec says so.**

`NaN` is the only value in JavaScript that is not equal to itself:

> A reliable way for ECMAScript code to test if a value X is a NaN is an expression of the form X !== X. The result will be true if and only if X is a NaN.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4

Answer (score 3):

This is why:

> NaN compares unequal (via ==, !=, ===, and !==) to any other value -- including to another NaN value.  Use Number.isNaN() or isNaN() to most clearly determine whether a value is NaN.  Or perform a self-comparison: NaN, and only NaN, will compare unequal to itself.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

> The initial value of Infinity is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY. The value Infinity (positive infinity) is greater than any other number. This value behaves mathematically like infinity; for example, any positive number multiplied by Infinity is Infinity, and anything divided by Infinity is 0.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity

What you also might be interested in is using the `isFinite` method of `Number`:

```
Number.isFinite(Infinity);  // false
Number.isFinite(NaN);       // false
```

Read up on Number.isFinite(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite

Comment: This is the most complete answer with the best explanation IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Because processors interpret it that way. Most math in JS follows the [IEEE-754 specification for floating math arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which processors implement in pretty specific ways. That includes `NaN !== NaN` and `Infinity === Infinity`, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

`infinity` is treated as a numeric value, so `infinity==infinity` represents one numeric value equaling another. While in common mathematics the infinity can not be compared against infinity, in javascript it can!

`NaN` on the other hand, is a type of undefined variable, not a number. So comparisons between `NaN` are not logically comparable. The proper way to compare against `NaN` is with the function `isNaN`.

Example:

`isNaN(NaN) // returns true`

Comment: That’s not really true. Both `Infinity` and `NaN` are, in fact, numbers and numeric values. The spec just treats `NaN` as unequal to itself (and any other value).